# Как добавить класс всем элементам коллекции и удалить класс у всех элементов?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
let header = document.querySelector(".menu-ul");
let menuList = document.querySelectorAll(".list")
;
console.log(pageYOffset);
window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
    let y = this.pageYOffset;
    if(y>1000){
        header.classList.add("sticky")
        for (let i = 0; i < menuList; i++) {
          menuList.classList.toggle("sticky");
          console.log(j);
      }
    }     
    else{
        header.classList.remove("sticky")
    }
})
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

вот так

```
let header = document.querySelector(".menu-ul");
let menuList = document.querySelectorAll(".list")

window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
    let y = this.pageYOffset;
    if(y>1000){
        header.classList.add("sticky")
        for(let item of menuList) {
            item.classList.add("sticky")
        }
    }
    else{
        header.classList.remove("sticky")
        for(let item of menuList) {
            item.classList.remove("sticky")
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Если разница только в добавлении и удалении классов, то можете написать так коротко:

```js
const header = document.querySelector(".menu-ul");
const menuList = document.querySelectorAll(".list");

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const y = this.pageYOffset;
    const isBig = y > 1000;
    const action = isBig ? 'add' : 'remove';
    const className = 'sticky';

    header.classList[action](className);

    menuList.forEach(item => item.classList[action](className));
})
```